# How do I get the roles of a user using the Membership class

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a Login.aspx page by using the `Membership` class. I check the username and password by using `Membership.ValidateUser(txtUsern.Text, txtPass.Text)`
and now I want to get the role of this user.
Is there a method in the `Membership` class to get the role of the user?

Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following code

```
string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser("userName");
```

The above roles string array will contain all the roles for your user.
Besides this if the user is logged in you can check if the user is in a particular role or not using

```
if(Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
{
//your code
}
```

here "Admin" is the role.

Comment: thanks, I cant use Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") in front of IF, so I was convert it to bool but I have ERR again, "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'."  do you have a solution?

Comment: Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") returns bool

Comment: to get the roles of user use
string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser("userName");

Answer (score 2):

[`Roles.GetRolesForUser` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13z1h26k)

```
String[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(); // roles of currently logged-on user
```

or

```
roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName); // roles of the user with the specified username
```

Comment: thanks, but value of roll become 0, do u know what is the cause?

Comment: @user1492770: I can't follow, what _value_ of what _roll_ becomes _0_?

Comment: String[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(); value of roles

Comment: What RoleProvider are you using, the default `SqlRoleProvider`? Is the user authenticated(`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`)? Does the user already has roles? I would recommend to read some tutorials like this: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx